# jQuery on-screen HOW-TO / HELP

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, frameworks

I am contemplating doing "interactive" tutorials on a website i'm developing

The point of this would be the first time a user visits a specific area or functionality of a site, or if they click help an interactive "session" could start, that guides the user hand in hand trough a series of steps, buttons would be highlighted with an arrow or some other kind of indication, i'm thinking in the ways of some game tutorials that exists.

i'd think you would need to be able to assign "tasks" the user needs to peform to get to the next step of the tutorial like

- Click this button (arrow pointing)
- Write 'something' in this field (arrow pointing, perhaps automaticly starting to write it as an example)

And then assorted ways of display notes or areas of interrest together with the notes, dimming parts of the screen. anything like this exists or would I have to start writing something like this from scratch? :)

Wondered if a jquery plugin for some sort of tutorial framework exists, alternatively if anyone has any ideas they would be welcome.

Comment: please clarify your meaning. When I read "live" I am thinking "live help, there is a person at the other end helping you". "Interactive" can be programmatic. User sets focus on text box, a "tip" shows up to explain how to do XXX?

Comment: I've removed the "live" part of the question to clarify that I just mean interactive, kinda like a "helping hand", showing a tip on focus is rather simple, but could be something you would want to do in the middle of a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up your text editor and get ready to start writing a lot of code.

There basically can't be plugin for this, because nobody knows the semantics of your tutorial. And preparing a framework, which would make it possible is imo much harder, than writing it for specific scenario. It definitelly is possible to create, but I wouldn't hope for any one line of code magic plugin :)

Comment: It would basicly be a framework that I hoped existed, something where you could tie a specific dom element to something in the tutorial, because as you say the tutorial itself is usually specific for a certain scenario :)

Comment: This is something so specific, that I don't see how could you generalize it to make a framework. It would end as a bunch of functions that would encapsulate some basic actions anyway. Btw: You will need to connect this with some storage (to keep track of users progress etc). This won't be a simple task at all if you your tutorial contains many steps and scenarios. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "silver bullet" to do what you want. As @Dampe points out your content is going to be specific to your needs. The [jquery tooltip](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/tooltip#A_loose_mix_of_different_options) is best *canned* option here. It isn't a perfect solution but if you look at some of the examples on [This JQUERY TOOLTIP Demo Page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/) there are some slick options. If you can figure out what places you want help to appear for your user (like when focus is set on a particular text box) you can launch a tool off of a focus event rather than a mouseover. This should give you some 'mid stream' options.
Also, notice on the demo page that you can 'block or unblock' tool tips, so that if you have a 'regular' customer you can block the tips so that they have an uninterrupted experience.